# WPF , Switching between multiple windows without Disposing

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I have 3 windows and I am able to switch between them fine. The problem i am running into is the windows aren't saving the data when hidden. I think somewhere they are getting disposed, but i'm not sure how. I have a textbox on two windows to test this. It worked fine when there was only two windows, but adding the third created this problem. Here is my main window.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private AutoImport auto;
    private DTLegacy dleg;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MainWindow(AutoImport parent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        auto = parent;
    }

    public MainWindow(DTLegacy parent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dleg = parent;
    }

    private void btnAutoImport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        if (auto == null) { auto = new AutoImport(); }
        auto.Show();
    }

    private void btnDTLegacy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        if (dleg == null) { dleg = new DTLegacy(); }
        dleg.Show();
    }
}
```

Window 1

```
public AutoImport()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    MainWindow main = new MainWindow(this);
    main.Show();
}
```

Window 2

```
public DTLegacy()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    MainWindow main = new MainWindow(this);
    main.Show();
}
```

I'm thinking the answer might be to create a window class of some sort, but i'm not sure what this would look like.

Comment: There are 2 concepts. In `wpf` (together with `mvvm`) preferable is when window is disposed. Simply keep ALL properties you need to restore state in view model: focus, selections, entered/chosen values, etc. Another concept would be to create windows once and then never dispose them (famous `winforms` `Hide` trick), it should still work in wpf. Create windows instances at startup and never ever again create instance (like you do!), but call that instance `Hide()` / `Show()` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you creating a new `MainWindow` instance each time? You're currently hiding it, so show it again instead of creating a new one.
Assuming it's the main Window of your application and `AutoImport`/`DTLegacy` are "child" windows, one solution would be to pass the `MainWindow` instance as parameter of the "child" windows, so you can call `.Show()` easily:

```
private MainWindow parent;
public AutoImport(MainWindow parent)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.parent = parent;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    this.parent.Show();
}
```